# How to Call WCF service from biztalk

Tags: wcf, biztalk, orchestration

I am new to `Biztalk` (Stack Overflow as well) I want to receive an `xml schema file` containing 2 digits and send it to WCF service which will do some arithematic operation on them and give me answer in a file as well. I have tried a lot but unfortunately couldn't succeeded.

What I have done...

I created a service and host it to `IIS`. It is running fine. I have tested it through `(WCFTestClient.exe)`. Then I have created a `biztalk project` and `Consume WCF` Service from generated items. Then I deployed the project. And configured Receive and Send ports accordingly but have no luck.....

Comment: There are so many things which could be wrong that it's impossible to start helping you with the information you have provided. You didn't even post an error. Have you looked in BizTalk admin or the event log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem myself. Actually I read error message in suspended service messages in Biztalk Administration Console and after some google I was able to solve the issue.